# Adding optional tag in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement wherein I need to add ID element in the request xml using xsl.

Schema is like

```
 <body>
<A/>
<!--optional-->
<B/>
<!--optional-->
<C/>
<!--optional-->
<D/>
</body>
```

Here ideally I have to add element ID after element `<D>`, but since it is optional I have to check if D exists and then add element ID  after it. If 'D' doesn't exist then I have to check for C, B and ultimately if all the optional element doesn't exist then I have to add element `<ID>` after `<A>`.

I used or notation to match template but its not working.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a 2 or 3 test cases please? A test case is a sample input document and the expected output for that input. Also what version of XSLT are you using? 1.0? 2? or 3?

Comment: XSLT is 2.0,

I have just stated the scenario, testcase may be like,
request
<body>
<A>20</A>
<!--optional-->
<B>15</B>
<!--optional-->
</body> ..... then the xsl has to first search for element 'D' if it exists, and then 'C', since both doesn't exist then it has append the id value '10' after element 'B'. 
Expected output be like,
<body>
<A>20</A>
<!--optional-->
<B>15</B>
<ID>10</ID>
</body>

Comment: Shouldn't matter where you place ID, as long as it's a child of body...

Comment: Request has sequence enabled so it requires the ID to be placed appropriately otherwise the request will get failed in downstream.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0" >

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />    


<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <ID>10</ID>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will transform input document ...

```
<body>
<A/>
<!--optional-->
<B/>
<!--optional-->
<C/>
<!--optional-->
<D/>
</body>
```

... into output document ...

```
<body>
  <A /><!--optional-->
  <B /><!--optional-->
  <C /><!--optional-->
  <D />
  <ID>10</ID>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you it actually works.. But i have another issue, let me state it like this I have another element <E> which comes after element <D> which is mandatory element. I want to place <ID> before element <E> and after element <A> also checking optional elements. I tried to execute this scenario from your provided xsl but its adding the ID element at the end of request.

Comment: In actual the request schema will not remain same, in some of the requests I need to insert ID between element <B> and <C> in some of the requests I have to inset ID at the end. So I want a logic to check all the above optional elements one by one, and if any element present I want to append ID value beneath that element.